# Skin doesn't change after I edit and upload it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Half of my custom skin doesn't change when I edit it and save and upload it and it's frustrating because I'm just trying to make that half black... Can anyone help me out? It's only the legs and arms that aren't turning black when I want them to...

I'm using 1.7.10, but it let me change my skin before but not now, so it's just weird.

[image: texture file]

[image: This is what it supposed to look like]

[image: This is what happens when i boot up my game, I have it uploaded right too]

[image]

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do and how did you recolor the skin? Can you provide any screenshots or images (and the skin itself)?

Comment: So you're changing only one half and that half doesn't change? Isn't that the same as saying that your skin isn't changing at all? Only one half changing would be an extremely strange bug. But yes, please attach the old and new skin and a screenshot how it looks in the game, that way we can better understand what you mean.